# RStudio empty on startup - No windows, no menus, no rendering

Tags: r, rstudio

When I start RStudio, none of the windows inside the main frame come up, and none of the menu options display menu options when clicked.  It's just an blank page.

It feels like some kind of graphics rendering or window management problem.

I'm running Windows 7.  I have the latest version of R, which is 3.1.1.  I have the latest RStudio, which is 98.1062.

How to fix it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but James' answer doesn't help. Did you ever get it figured out?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reset the RStudio state.  Do this:

- Close RStudio if open.
- Go to this directory: %localappdata%\RStudio-Desktop
- Rename that directory as a type of backup.
- Start RStudio.

RStudio will see the configuration directory is missing and regenerate it with correct values.

Everything should work after that.

Other threads I found helpful here are:

- https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-s-State
- https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200666647-RStudio-096-16-Windows-7-gives-empty-screen?locale=en-us

Thanks!

Comment: still not working for me too : I'm using Rstudio 0.99 on windows 7 enterprise

Comment: Should also perhaps delete `%APPDATA%\Rstudio\`

Answer (score 7):

Renaming the RStudio state by renaming %localappdata%\RStudio-Desktop did not work for me. However i made it work by renaming another config folder in %appdata% instead.

- Close RStudio
- Go to this directory: %appdata%\RStudio
- Rename the folder
- Restart RStudio

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue when I downgraded my version of R.
I did try the above solutions. However, it didn't work for me.

After some googling, I found out that the issue was because now I had a different version of R installed. Here's how you can choose the version of R and rectify the issue.

- Navigate to the RStudio installation folder. (C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin)
- Press and hold Control Key
- Double click on rstudio.exe
- Choose a specific version of R (whichever you want to work with)

Click OK and RStudio should open without any issues.

NB: I use 64bit Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

Search this [documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/4.4.0/doc/pdf/TIB_terr_Using-TERR-with-RStudio.pdf) for '**Blank GUI**'.

This is what I found which worked for me:

> 1. In Windows Explorer, go to C:\Users\currentUser\AppData\Roaming\RStudio.
> 2. Delete the Desktop.ini file
>
> This technique forces RStudio to refresh and default to open-source R as the engine

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I almost gave up about solving it but then I found a suggestion that GitHub might be the problem. I am not sure how that is happening but the minute I uninstalled GitHub and re-launched Rstudio, it worked perfectly as nothing happened!? Here is the link for where I found the suggestion on Rstudio community page: (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200983187-R-studio-0-98-797-for-mac-opens-as-blank-white-page)

Comment: @naltipar This is not a link-only answer. The link is only provided as a reference. The post itself contains an answer.

Comment: I had the same issue with github. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and figured out that for some reason R was blocked on the step of loading my library from a website (I added it to Rprofile for auto-load). You can test the following:

1) Try to run just R console, not RStudio, and then click on blank space - normally some information should appear
2) Try to launch without network connection

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac (Running Yosemite 10.10.3) this is what worked for me:

1. Move/Rename ~/.rstudio-desktop
   (Many responses have mentioned this, but this by itself didn't help.)
2. Then I **shutdown my Mac and restarted** it. RStudio worked when I logged back in.

Before that, I tried every one of the steps mentioned here and in many other links, including re-downloading R and RStudio, but unfortunately none of those steps helped in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue I faced so I unistalled the windows installer and downloaded zip version from this link https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/

Unziped It and pasted it into c drive and created shortcut from Rstudio/bin/rstudio.exe file.

Working properly after that no issue. In windows installer checked that r session is not working due to an missing dll.

So try to install from ZIP

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem like Thomas

> When I start RStudio, none on the windows inside the main frame come up, and none of the menu options display menu options when clicked. It's just an blank page.

My problem was, that i uninstalled R because is thought RStudio will work on its own.

So i uninstalled RStudio and deleting every existing file which was created by R or RStudio.

In the next step i installed RStudio again.

It was asking for a Version of R (which i dont had in this state). So i installed R again and everything is working fine now. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had a slight variation of the problem that might be of interest. I had set up an aliases.cmd to run my cygwin bash shell automatically upon launch of a cmd terminal as per:

- https://superuser.com/questions/302194/automatically-executing-commands-when-a-command-prompt-is-opened

What RStudio was doing was launching a few cmd windows in the background to (I assume) populate each pane and the console.

This was triggering a bash shell which wasn't returning and was hanging RStudio.
If you have this issue you can just manually kill the sub bash terminals spawned by cmd via ProcessExplorer/TaskManager and RStudio will continue to launch normally.

If anyone else has set anything to launch automatically on init of a cmd terminal then this could interfere in the same way with RStudio. 
The RStudio devs could probably fix this behind the scenes by changing the way they spawn cmd terminals in the gui.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. After trying the options above with no luck, I uninstalled Rx64 3.5.0 and installed an older version, R x64 3.2.2. 
Rstudio then worked perfect.