# R Studio freezes on load

Tags: r, rstudio

When I open R Studio it loads "R Notebook" and freezes there indefinitely. I've tried uninstalling it and also R but that didn't help. I am not sure what the problem is since it was working fine before.

Anyone has knows why this might be happening?

Comment: Perhaps contact RStudio for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RStudio empty on startup - No windows, no menus, no rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978779/rstudio-empty-on-startup-no-windows-no-menus-no-rendering)

Comment: also s. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/201900087-R-studio-blank-upon-opening, https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115007322368-RStudio-opens-blank-R-scripts or https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488508-RStudio-Desktop-Will-Not-Start

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with the same problem... In my case, the problem has also with Qt qtwebengineprocess consuming a lot of CPU, as described [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-freezing-and-qt-webengine-eating-cpu/28019), [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/qtwebengineprocess-100-cpu/43583) or [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/high-cpu-usage-when-scrolling/32093)

I tried to exclude .RData, and project file (.RProj)... it does not work... the only way to solve the issue was to delete the project folder which is usually hidden project folder (the folder .Rproj.user).

The above three steps enable to open the R Studio, and create a new project file (from existing directory).

Usually the above suffices, but it appears sometimes do not solve the issue with a specific .Rmd. When it happened, it was solved just copy-and-pasting the .Rmd file into another folder and working from there...

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason it may happen that you created rather big object(s) in R session, e.g. with `m <- matrix(seq.int(5e8), ncol = 10)` (1.9 Gb), then the project session was saved in .Rdata file & .RDataTmp files. It takes big amount of time to load them. So if the data in your session are not vital you can just delete it from the project's home directory (indicated in yellow below).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me sometimes when the prior R session failed or closed abruptly.  If you close RStudio and then double click on another *.R or *.Rmd file to kick start RStudio, it will skip the "normal" startup that is corrupted for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue with RStudio Server.
A project crashed when I tried to open a Rmd file. Now every time I tried to re-open that project it ran into the "R Notebook ..." freeze.
Took me some time to figure it out, but this approach worked for me at least:

- open a terminal or open RStudio in another project that is not corrupt
- navigate into the corrupt project folder
- enable "view hidden files"
- delete the `.Rproj.user` folder
- try again to open the project