# RStudio empty at start

Tags: r, rstudio

Seemingly out of nowhere, RStudio fails to start properly on my machine, creating a white small window, but nothing else.

[image]

I followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978779/rstudio-empty-on-startup-no-windows-no-menus-no-rendering) and [here](http://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488508-RStudio-Desktop-Will-Not-Start), but the problem persists. I reinstalled both R and RStudio to the latest version, tried to run in admin mode but nothing would help. Running `version` in R  returns

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.0                         
year           2019                        
month          04                          
day            26                          
svn rev        76424                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
nickname       Planting of a Tree
```

When I pres `crtl` while RStudio is starting it does ask me which R distribution to run, and the path which is stated there indeed exists and points to the R distribution which works just fine when you execute it directly.

Next, in `C:\Users\myusername\Documents` an empty RHISTORY file and a folder `R` containing a `win-library` folder which contains an empty folder called `3.5` (or 3.6 if I run it on R 3.6) gets created every I launch and close RStudio. Deleting these files does not help.

Finally, after installing an older RStudio version (1.0.153) it works!

Comment: Can you go into Rstudio, Tools>Global Options>R Version at top of window. What does that show? Set it to the path of your R installation and restart everything and see if it sticks.

Comment: no, if i click on windows Rstudio preview to maximize, nothing happens. The only thing I can do is press `ctrl` in order to choose which R to run but it is linking to the correct one. I installed and older version (3.5.3) but the problem persists.